# if/else test equivalents for case control statement in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, switch-statement

I am writing a script in bash to easily loop some software, and depending on the inputs select a different strategy to use for a particular run. For example whether or not to run on all the files in a directory or just a subset, and whether files are paired or independent. (I'm working with fastq files if you an tell)

Usually I prefer to write case control statement whenever I have 3 or more options because I find it is easier to interpret and maintain. However I want to be able to test if certain files exist similar to when if/else statements in bash do `if [ -e $foo ]; then etc` That got me wondering if case control statements have any equivalent test options to if/else statements [example](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

More specifically I want to know if its possible to test for the existence of a file with a case statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` doesn't have any test options; the `test` command (also spelled `[`) does. `if` and `case` do two separate things. `case` compares a single *value* to a number of patterns to see which matches. `if` and `elif` checks the exit status of a *command*. It just happens that `test`/`[` is far and away the most command command used with an `if` statement.

Each test like `-e`, `-d`, etc, corresponds to a call to a system call named `stat` which returns far more information than any one test actually uses; that information is just discarded. You *could* run an external program wrapper around `stat` (also called `stat`) yourself manually, then pattern match on its output with a `case` statement. That is a little less efficient, since it involves running an external program just to access the system call. However, the `bash` distribution does come with a `stat` built-in that you could to compile and enable yourself to mitigate that problem.

(The change log for `bash` 5 mentions a new loadable builtin for `stat`—among other commands—, but it doesn't seem any different than the one that I though has been available for a while.)